How to test a share operation to a PWA on Android?
I need to write a helper PWA that will receive shared content from an application and forward it further.
I am an amateur dev (this is a home-grade PWA) and while I have written PWAs before, I never needed to test its actual interaction with the mobile device.
Worst case I will, for my tests, just assume that I receive such and such content on the endpoint defined in the manifest and go from there, then build and install the app and test it in real life. I want to make that last part as straightforward as possible during development (and possibly simulate the sharing process - I did not find anything relevant in the Chrome or FF dev tools).
